# linux dup2 and printf

Tags: c, linux, dup2

I am trying using dup2 redirect stdout to another file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
  int newfd;
  if ((newfd = open("output_file.txt", O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, 0644)) < 0) {
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("Luke, I am your...\n");
  dup2(newfd, 1);
  printf("Foobar.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When the  first `printf` prints a newline `\n`, `Luke, I am your...` will be printed to the screen and `Foobar` will be written to *output_file.txt*, if the first printf does not print a new line `printf("Luke, I am your...");`, both string will be written to output_file.txt. So seems printf will write the first string to a buffer when there is not a newline(`\n`).

What really happens underlying then ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that when you don't have a newline `\n`, the string printed by `printf()` is buffered.  So the whole content of the buffer is printed to the file. This has nothing to do with second call to `printf()`.

If you do `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf()`, you won't see this behaviour irrespective of whether you have newline `'\n` in the first `printf()` or not. Because `fflush()` will clear(flush) all th output buffered until that point.

The reason for having the `\n` in `printf()` seems to work expected is because `printf()` is line-buffered when connected to a terminal device. So the `\n` triggers a flushing.

Answer (score 2):

The first string is still buffered in the FD when the FD is switched out beneath it. If you need to ensure that the FD is clear before switching then call `fflush(stdout)` first.